# Replace Item in Array does not always work

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
    let item = this.datasets.filter((item) => item.id === tableRow.id);
    if (item && item.length != 0) {
        // Update case
        item[0] = tableRow; 
    }
```

it does not update the item correctly. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work.

I replaced the above code with the following:

```
    let index = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.datasets.length; i++) {
        if (this.datasets[i].id === tableRow.id) {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (index !== -1) {
        // Update case (delete + insert)
        this.datasets.splice(index, 1, tableRow);
    }
```

This works always. What is wrong with the first approach?

Thank you

Comment: item is a new array, updating element in the item doesn't reflect in main array

Comment: Use `let index = this.datasets.findIndex((item) => item.id === tableRow.id); if(index > -1) this.datasets.splice(index,1,tableRow) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `item` holds a new array returned by the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, so changing elements in the `item` array doesn't make any change to `datasets` array.

---

You can even simplify the second approach using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method.

```
let index = this.datasets.findIndex((item) => item.id === tableRow.id);
if(index > -1) this.datasets.splice(index,1,tableRow)
```